# Broken HLS m3u8 file works on vlc

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, wowza, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I have a .m3u8 file which pints to invalid  aes key URL but it seems working fine on VLC. How is this possible.I attached a snap of my .m3u8 file [image]

Comment: Anyone ?? I want to restrict playback if the playlist is broken but I am stuck at this point

Comment: It works because you didn't encrypt your media files. There are many resources and answers on stackoverflow that explain how it works.

Comment: @aergistal you are correct thanks for your comment cheers

Comment: @aergistal Btw do you know whay vlc can't play AES 128 ENCRYPTED .m3u8 file even with the key file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out that simply specifying  #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://local" this tag with no values doe not prevent media from playing. But we need to properly encrypt our media files I found this nice tool mp4hls it allows me to generate AES  128 encrypted m3u8 FROM .mp4 If anyone having the same problems hope this help
https://www.bento4.com/developers/hls/